# Bypass javascript sanitizer

Tags: javascript, encoding, xss

I have a javascript sanitizer where I replace '<', '>' and '&' with their respective character encodings.

`str.replace(/[&<>]/g, encoding);`

This sanitized data is inserted into the DB and then rendered as HTML.

Like,


`<?php echo $col1 . "\n" $col2 . "\n"; ?>`

Is it possible to break this sanitizer ?

Comment: What is it used for?

Comment: @zerkms Have edited the question.

Comment: It's not clear: Are you receiving already escaped HTML that you want to save without escaping? Why are you escaping it before you're saving it?

Comment: @tadman I'm escaping before saving it because I don't want any javascript to be entered into the DB. Say like <script>alert(document.cookie);</script>

Comment: The database doesn't care what's in there, it's not going to suddenly run that. What you're talking about is a display issue where anything that comes out of the database *cannot be trusted* and must be escaped accordingly. You should be concerned with escaping if and when you display the data, not when you persist it. This means that if your sanitization rules change over time, you won't have to spin through all the older records and fix them. Also if you relax your rules, your older content will render properly rather than having content permanently deleted.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the sanitization on the client. You should probably do it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but it's going to replace <, >, and & with a single string, not their respective encoded strings. It also may not be efficient, as there is a browser-native method, `createTextNode`.

```
function escapeHtml(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return div.innerHTML;
};
```

http://shebang.mintern.net/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript/

However, this still may not be safe, since the client can modify the javascript to prevent this encoding. It'd be much safer to do this in the backend.